# Select a Month from X Months back

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a SQL table that has a two columns and I'm needing for the script to print the month based on the range for it to go back too.

Example: If the range is 8 and the current month is Jun then it should return Oct

This is where I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle a range that goes backwards when the value is a negative or 0. I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Table:

```
MonthNum    Month
1           Jan
2           Feb
3           Mar
4           Apr
5           May
6           Jun
7           Jul
8           Aug
9           Sep
10          Oct
11          Nov
12          Dec
```

Current Code:

```
DECLARE @Month AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @MONTHTXT AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @GETMONTH AS VARCHAR(100)

/* Change the rnage for which month to select*/
SET @GETMONTH= (Select 1 as Range)

/*Get the desired month*/
SET @Month= (Select (MONTH(GETDATE())) - 1 as 'Month')

/*Convert the value to the correct text for the month*/
SET @MONTHTXT = (Select
                    CASE
                        WHEN @MONTH = '1' THEN 'Jan'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '2' THEN 'Feb'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '3' THEN 'Mar'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '4' THEN 'Apr'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '5' THEN 'May'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '6' THEN 'Jun'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '7' THEN 'Jul'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '8' THEN 'Aug'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '9' THEN 'Sep'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '10' THEN 'Oct'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '11' THEN 'Nov'
                        WHEN @MONTH = '12' THEN 'Dec'
                        ELSE 'N/A'
                        End As 'Month'
                )
                
Print @MONTHTXT
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your sample code is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just use the built in functions?

```
select datename(month, dateadd(month, -8, getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the date

```
Select FORMAT(DATEADD(month, @Range, GETDATE()), 'MMM', 'es-es') as 'Month'
```

The expresion "DATEADD(month, @Range, GETDATE())"

Then with the format get the month in string

With the example where range = -1

```
Select FORMAT(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()), 'MMM', 'es-es') as 'Month'
```

The result should be Month = 'May'